# How to stop database table from sorting values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

That is a table in mysql, the 010 is expected to be the last on the table. How do I handle that? The database automatically sort the values entered which id not needed [image: 1]

Comment: *Why* is `010` expected to be the last row? Can you show the DDL?

Comment: looking at a composite  ID where it  will have VST/01, VST02, ...VST09, VST010

Comment: Bummer about the down votes on the question :-(

Comment: Is your question more like "How do I browse a database in record-entry order in phpmyadmin?"

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is basically "show the rows in the sequence entered," which (strictly-speaking) is undefined in SQL.

What I usually do with my tables is add an ID column like:

```
create table foo (id int not null primary key auto_increment, ...rest of columns...)
```

This way, the rows are sortable by sequence-of-entry.  It doesn't have to be the primary key, either--any auto_increment column will work. (auto_increment is a MySqlism, btw, other RDBMSes have other syntax to do basically the same thing).

BTW, your column is, strictly speaking, sorting correctly--looks like it's a char or varchar column, so it's sorting in lexicographical order rather than numeric.  If you want to port your data over, I expect you can do something like:

```
insert into new_table
select * from old_table order by CAST(Visitorsid AS UNSIGNED)
```

At least I think that works...don't have a MySQL command line handy to try it :-). Good luck!

(Updated to fix MySQL syntax and use the right column name)

Answer (score 0):

Database tables are unsorted sets, and have no intrinsic order. If you want to get the rows in a specific order, you'll have to specify it explicitly, with an `order by` clause:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     mytable
ORDER BY CAST(visitorsid AS INTEGER)
```

Comment: I think what's happening here is that phpmyadmin is automagically slapping in an ORDER BY $col1, $col2... under the covers here.  If OP were to use your query instead of phpmyadmin's default what-you-get-when-you-click-browse-table, he'd get the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the order of a character field by its length, instead of standard collation order.

`SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE ORDER BY LENGTH(visitorid);`

I should add that by the leading 0 I assume this is not a numeric field.